# Converting python program to a usable exe safety

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

I have written my python program with a Gui. Now i wanna use this tool in my company.

for this I need an .exe so others can use it.

I know my code. But now i have to compile my code to an .exe file with a third party tool like pyinstaller or pyuic.

How can I be sure this open source tools are safe to use in my company without risking any hackers infiltrated this tools?

Is there any official way or tool to make a usable windows program from a py file?

Comment: The thing about open source code is that it is available for the public to read. That is how you ensure the source code is "safe" for open source projects. For closed source/proprietary code, you use contracts and the threat of legal action to ensure this.

Answer (score 0):

The "official way" to load PyInstaller is done via the `pip` command.

Open source does not mean everybody can edit the code that ist officialy distributed. If you would edit a copy of a printed law in your house does not mean that the law changes for everyone. Official commits are reviewed and checked against malicious edits.

Did you ever question other Python packages you loaded into your machine? They are distributed the same way.

Malicious actors will sometimes make clones of packages and publish them with a similar name in order to get lucky when people makea typo in the `pip` command. This is something you should always check.